# npx running both beta and latest tag

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I need my users to be able to run via npx the @latest version of my software, or a @beta, whichever is the most recent.
Is there a way with a single command?

At the moment they need to modify the command at every "phase switch".

I tried searching the manual, google, github issues, and specifying random operators.